# How to find the number of columns within a row key in hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

How to find the number of columns within a row key in hbase (since a row can  have many columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a direct way to do that as each row can have a different number of columns and they may be spread over several files.

If you don't want to bring the whole row to the client to perform the count there you can write an endpoint coprocessor (HBase version for a stored procedure if you like) to perform the calculation on the region server side and only return the result. you can read a little about coprocessors [here](https://blogs.apache.org/hbase/entry/coprocessor_introduction)

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple way:

Use hbase shell to scan through the table and write the output to a intermediate text file. Because hbase shell output splits each column of a row into a new line, we can just count the lines inside the text file (minus the first 6 lines which are hbase shell standard output and the last 2 lines).

```
echo "scan 'mytable', {STARTROW=>'mystartrow', ENDROW=>'myendrow'}" | hbase shell > row.txt
wc -l row.txt
```

Make sure to select the appropriate row keys, as the borders are not inclusive.

If you are only interested into specific columns (families), apply the filters in the hbase shell command above (e.g. FamilyFilter, ColumnRangeFilter, ...).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for @user3375803, actually you don't have to use external txt file. Because I can not comment on your answer, so I leave my answer below:

```
echo "scan 'mytable', {STARTROW=>'mystartrow', ENDROW=>'myendrow'}" | hbase shell | wc -l | awk '{print $1-8}'
```

Comment: Can you explain your code and how this answers the question?

Comment: First two pipelines are same as @user3375803 's answer. Third pipeline 'wc -l' can get row number without external txt file, while fourth pipeline "awk '{print $1-8}'" is aim to get third pipeline's result minus 8(first 6 lines and last 2 lines are not columns as original answer said)